# Choose dissertation topic for masters in computer science

Tags: thesis, masters, computer-science

I am pursuing my masters in CS and I have to come up with the dissertation topic on my own. It's very confusing to me and I am not able to come to any conclusion as to how to narrow down to specific topic in cloud computing(want to do my dissertation in this) . I know basics of cloud computing.

What can I do that will help me in narrowing down to a specific topic. My university requires me to come up with the topic and I am thinking about doing phd so I want to get my hands on research to see if I will be a good fit in phd.

My university does not have good professors who have done some good research work, so I am on my own.
Can someone please help me in this situation.

Comment: For your Master's thesis, I doubt you are required to find any original results.  Why don't you start with a general literature survey of the area you are interested in?  You can narrow it down as you are doing that general survey.  Note, this approach, doing a literature survey, will give you good preparation for your PhD work.